# basic java design approach for memeber fields

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose you have this low level work Java class with a public method with input parameters and other private methods to manipulate this input data .
Which is the preferable approach : set the input data into member fields so no need to pass it between private methods, or pass it as parameters to private methods?

Comment: In this general form this question cannot be answered. Please provide some reasoning and usecase for your question, so that there is a context.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, and opinion-based questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. My personal opinion is that if the member fields don't represent state, then they are just like global variables - use as little as possible, subject to clarity. But these sort of things can be argued back and forth, hence not on-topic.

Comment: why opinion ?? I'm looking for experience knowledge that become design pattern. not for my grandmother opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here isn't passing the value between private methods, it's how you perceive the state of the object. In other words, does it make sense for the instance to retain the value of the parameter you passed.

Consider, for example, a `Builder` class styled after [Bob the Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_the_Builder) - he fixes many things, but once he's done fixing something, it's fixed. It's no longer related to Bob. On the other hand, he wears a helmet, and takes it with him wherever he goes - its part of his state:

```
public class Builder {
    private String name;
    private Helmet helmet;

    public Builder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    /* Helmet methods - helmet is a data member */

    public void wearHelmet(Helmet helmet) {
        this.helmet = helmet;
    }

    public void adjustHelmet() {
        helmet.adjust();
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        helmet.raise();
    }


    /* Can he fix it? Yes he can! But he doesn't keep it afterwards */

    public void fix(It it) {
        straighten(it);
        paint(it);
        shine(it);
    }

    private void straighen(It it) {
        // implementation
    }

    private void paint(It it) {
        // implementation
    }

    private void shine(It it) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting parameters into private fields forces a certain sharing pattern onto users of your API. Specifically, the users must think how your objects must be shared in their environment to prevent issues when calling your APIs concurrently. Another alternative to this would be for you to lock other users of the API out with `synchronized` to prevent concurrent runs of the API at all, but that is an even worse approach.

I would stay with passing parameters around, so that your methods remain re-entrant. Another approach is to create a "per-request" object - a parameter holder object created by your API upon entry, which is used to pass arguments around.